# Laravel submit data with ajax not work errer TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

This Code  not work :  error in token but it's exist in form and ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">

              jQuery(document).on('click','.add-product', function(event){

                     event.preventDefault();
                  var product_image = $('#product_image').prop('files')[0];
                  var _token = '{{csrf_token()}}';
                  var product_name = $('#product_name').val();
                  var product_description = $('#product_description').val();
                  var product_price = $('#product_price').val();
               var product_status = $( "#product_status option:selected").val();
            var product_section = $( "#product_section option:selected").val();
                    var data = new FormData();
                    data.append( _token ,_token);
                   data.append( product_name ,product_name);
                   data.append( product_description ,product_description);
                   data.append( product_price ,product_price);
                   data.append( product_status ,product_status);
                   data.append( product_section ,product_section);
                   data.append( product_image ,product_image);
                  data.append( product_file ,product_file);


                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url:url+'/admin-cp/add-new-product',
                        type: 'POST',
                        cache:false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: data,
                        contentType:false,//"multipart/form-data",
                        processData:false, 
                        success: function(response){
                           jQuery('body').html(response.data);
                           //alert("Done");
                        },
                    });

                });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be effective if you csrf token send in header
[csrf](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-ajax-tokenmismatchexception)

Answer (score 0):

in laravel for ajax request it is convenient to use this

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">


 $.ajaxSetup({
               headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
               }
           });
```

read this and everything will turn out
[Laravel CSRF-token for ajax request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding   `{{csrf_token()}}` to your form

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
```